# How can i change the Pictures/Documents/etc directory?

Tags: directory, home-directory, xdg

I am a total noob in Ubuntu, and i would like to change the default directory of Documents, Music, Pictures etc. My setting is as follows:

- 1 partition for Windows
- 1 partition for ubuntu
- 1 partition in NTFS format for Storage.
  In that particular partition I store the Documents, Pictures etc for Windows.

Now I would like to make the exact same folders that store these stuff in Windows, to store the same stuff in Ubuntu as well. I used the tips I found in one post here, mentioning how to change the lines like this in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="/home/common/Music"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Movies"
```

and indeed it works fine, but every time I restart the machine, it's reset to simple "$Home/", without pointing to any actual directory. I mean that if I open the Documents folder, it takes me to an empty folder.

What is it that I'm doing wrong? How can I fix it? Many thanks in advance. (I use 14.04)

my fstab looks like that:

[image]

The terminal on the right side has the dev6, which is the partition i want to assign the Home folder to

Comment: what is the exact content of your `$HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file ?  Please, edit your post. Does this content change after a reboot ? How do you mount your NTFS partition ? may be it's mounted too late during boot or login. That could be why.

Comment: You do have to have partition mounted or it will not recognized different settings. And clicking on partition may auto mount it, but that is too late. You need to add to fstab so auto mounted during boot. I prefer linking which is another way to do it. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1811198

Comment: This might be the case, oldfred. But like i said, it's my first time in Ubuntu and i probably need a step by step guidance. :) If you'd be so kind, please guide me.

Here is the xdg text after i edit it: 

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30353620/screen1.png

and here it is after the restart.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30353620/screen3.png, 

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30353620/screen4.png

Comment: I downloaded Ubuntu tweak and it's supposed to be set to automount the disks... but the same thing happens every time i reboot. I don't know if i need to do it manually. If so, please tell me how. Thank you.

Comment: What is the content of `/etc/fstab`. Edit your question above  with that.

Comment: I thought post #4 in link I gave has details on adding an entry to fstab, changing permissions and linking folders in data partition? It would be the same for NTFS but you cannot change ownership & permissions. Your fstab entry needs to be slightly different.  See post #6 http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1983336

Comment: @solsTiCe I just added the fstab to the link above. Sorry that it's just a screenshot, i do not know how to paste it otherwise.

Comment: @oldfred I followed the instructions of post #6 and it worked like a charm. Million thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a line in your `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/sda6 /media/basislis/Storage ntfs rw,users,nosuid,nodev,default_permissions
```

This should automatically mount your NTFS share at boot and should normally fix the problem.

You may have to tweak the mount option. Look for documenation on that and educate yourself.